# Help with identification of a semiring with an "almost-inverse".

Tags: inverse, monoid, semiring

I'm working with an idempotent semiring which have families $C^v, \hat{C^v}$ of elements with the following properties:

$$ {C}^v_i \hat{C_i^v} = 1 $$
$$ \sum_i \hat{C_i^v} {C}^v_i = 1 $$
$$ {C}^v_i \hat{C_j^v} = 0 \quad\text{where}\quad i \neq j $$
$$ {C}^v_i \hat{C_j^w} = \hat{C_j^w} {C}^v_i  \quad\text{where}\quad v \neq w  $$

As we see $\hat{C_i^v}$ is close but not quite an inverse of $\hat{C_i^v}$.
Also the last property often does not fully hold in many cases.

*Have such or similar structures appeared or have been explored elsewhere?

Do any of these properties have a name that I could google?*

Thanks for any and all leads!

Comment: I also asked a [more detailed version of this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450256/semiring-axioms-which-almost-implement-inverse-searching-for-domains-other-than).